# JQUERY IE AJAX Success callback not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

currently using jq 1.4.2

And i have gone through this forum and other forums for a simple fix ... since so many have had this problem..but i have not found anything that seems to work hence i am posting this problem

```
        $(".editvolunteer").fancybox({
            'width'                : 970,
            'height'            : 460,
            'autoScale'            : false,
            'transitionIn'        : 'none',
            'transitionOut'        : 'none',
            'type'                : 'iframe',
            onClosed : function() {
              $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'html',
             cache: false, 
               url: "ajaxrosterupdate.php",
            data: "x=60",
              async: false,

        success: function(data) {        

              $("#updateroster").html(data);      <---- this work in FF            

        }
        success: function(resp, txtS, xhr) {
                           if (xhr.status==200) {      

                              alert(xhr.status);    <-- this alert box shows up in ie and FF

                                 } else {

                             //    alert(xhr.status);

                           }
        }

      }).responseText;



    }
       });
```

I dont know what i am doing wrong i have used debugbar and i can seethe html content that comes back i have used fiddler and i see the html content that comes back there....the xhr stat =200 so every thing is good..yet it does not replace the the content $("#updateroster").html(data).

I have been banging my head for the last 48 hrs and well i need help.

Comment: Are you sure the HTML coming back is *completely* valid?  IE may be discarding it, while FF is tolerating it.

Comment: good point ..so to test things out what i did was i deleted everything in the ajaxrosterupdate and just added <?php echo "hello" ?> and it did print that......should i just post the entire html it is reurning ?

Comment: @nick - you were right the problem was the html it had script tags that needed ot be removed and empty lines...i think i should have put it as another thread so it  helps someone

Comment: I'll add it below as an answer in hopes it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is ultimately using [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML) here, what it *seems* like is your markup coming back is invalid causing some issues.

If there's something wrong with the markup and you're seeing no error but an empty result, chances are one browser is tolerating that invalid HTML, showing it as best it can, and another browser may discard it entirely...which appears to be what IE is doing to you.